# Call R variable in Javascript chunk (in Rstudio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, web, rstudio

I am trying to call an R variable in JS chunk, but JS did not recognize it.
I think it is normal since R and JS run in different contexts.

I tried to save the R variable into a text file and then I tried to load it to JS but is seems like it did not recognize it neither.
Here is the JS code i used to read my R variable which is stored in txt file :

```
    $.get("./inter.txt", function(data) {
    var k = data;
     });
```

I tried different alternatives ("./inter.txt", "/inter.txt", "inter.txt","mypath/inter.txt")
The text file is in the same folder as my R project. I code in R but I am new to javascript.

Any idea guys ?

Comment: What do you mean "but JS did not recognize it"? It can't find the file? And unless you're interpreting the loaded text as R code, it's just plain text.

Comment: when I store a string in my variable K and run my javascript code, I can see it in output.
When I try to read the txt file which contain the same string, it fails.
I am not sure whether it fails to find the file or to read it or to store it.